# 2009 MBP goes to sleep 15 seconds after powering on and can't be woken up

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake

So, what happens is after a turn on the macbook, it goes through the normal startup sequence, then shows a blue screen, and shows the desktop, just like normal. but then, after 15 seconds, the screen, keyboard backlight, and apple logo power off and the sleep light starts pulsating, i can wake it sometimes, but everything stays shut off. I tried resetting the nvram and the smc countless times. i ran a hardware test and it gave me back an error that says that there is a damaged thermal battery sensor. i cant run internet recovery mode, safe mode gives me the same problem, single user is the only way i can get it to stay on.

The strange thing is, when i brought it to the computer repair place, he gave it back the next day saying it just needed a new battery, 2 days after that it worked with the charger plugged in, i replaced the battery with a factory new one, and the problem came back.

What the heck can I do about this?

Comment: The damaged sensor is inaccurately signaling the firmware on the MPB to put the computer to sleep to protect it from a dangerous level of heat. The sensor needs to be replaced.

Comment: Can i disable the sensor in single user mode? or unplug/unsolder it?

Comment: It could just be a disconnected/broken cable. Without the device on a bench in front of me, its hard to tell. Find a reputable repair shop.